# Any theory deals with spaces that mixes the size of the tuples?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, manifolds

Specifically, I am looking for for a theory that studies the properties of the set of a finite tuples of a set $X$.

Suppose for instance the set of the reals, A 2-d space can by constructed as the product $R \times R$.

But here, I am looking for a set that contains tuples of various sizes, for instance:

$$
R=\bigcup_{i=0}^n\mathbb{R}^i
$$

or

$$
N=\bigcup_{i=0}^n\mathbb{N}^i
$$

What 'cool' things can I do with this?

Comment: What about finite degree polynomials over a ring or field? They are similar to tuples of varying size.

Comment: @Anon21 You just defined them as sets. Which topology do you want? It just depends what you want to do with them, You can give them the disjoint union topology induced by the usual topologies used in each $\mathbb{R}^n$. Likewise, you can assign metrics. One example is to use $d(x,y))$ to be the distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(x,y)=1$, when they are  tuples of different sizes.

Comment: @JohnDouma, that is identifying tuples that are not the same in the sets defined in the question. For example $(1,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$, or in other words $1+x$ and $1+x+0x^2$.

Comment: It is not clear to me whether flags ([linear algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) or [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(geometry))) are responsive to your study.

Comment: @plop I suppose I am asking if there is any practical use for these sets. Are they used in any field to achieve a practical purpose?

Comment: If you don't care about order: take the subspace of finite subsets of a hyperspace $H(X)$ of $X$ (usually the set of non-empty closed subsets of a space, there are several usual topologies on it, I quite like the Vietoris topology); in a $T_1$ space (so all metric spaces), $\textrm{Fin}(X) \subseteq H(X)$ and it inherits a topology that way.

Comment: I imagine there are many ways to think about this, but I'll toss one out (in which I'm no expert at all). More generally, you might consider the set of $n$-tuples or real numbers with some possibly missing coordinates instead of with just the first $i$ coordinates. This set could be viewed naturally as the set $\mathcal P$ of partial functions (see Wikipedia or google) from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\mathbb R$. What you asked about would correspond naturally to the subset of $\mathcal P$ of partial functions with domain $\{1,2,\dots,i\}$ for some $i$.

Comment: You may be interested in the notion of [flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) (although they stop at a finite level).

Comment: *I am asking if there is any practical use for these sets* --- The set of finite strings from a given (usually countably infinite) alphabet is [commonly used in logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(formal_languages)#Notation). In descriptive set theory (and other places), two player games [make use of the set of finite strings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796199/13130). In these applications there is usually no upper bound on the string lengths, but certainly specific results might make use of strings whose lengths are less than or equal to some given positive integer $n.$